# Syntastic and hdevtools

Tags: haskell, ghc, syntastic

I followed the directions online from https://github.com/bitc/hdevtools/ and I am still seeing the following:

```
Syntastic: active mode enabled
Syntastic info for filetype: haskell
Available checker(s):
Currently enabled checker(s):
```

I can't find anything with Google. What am I doing wrong/still need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to cp hdevtools from where cabal installs it to somewhere that `$PATH` points to like `/usr/local/bin`. Same thing is true for `hlint` and `ghc-mod`.

Comment: Instead of manually installing executables, you should add `~/.cabal/bin` and `~/bin` to your path in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`